# In Quickbooks Desktop SDK, is there any way to modify the total tax on a sales transaction

Tags: c#, sdk, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm using QuickBooks desktop and interfacing via QBFC and C#.

QuickBooks calculates the VAT for each sales line, but from within the desktop, you can manually modify the total tax of the invoice.

Is there any way to perform this modification via the interface?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to work out the same thing - unfortunately setting the TaxAmount on the Sales Line doesn't have any impact. I was trying to do this to deal with discrepancies between imported data and calculated VAT, and managed to work around by using gross figures and setting the Sales Receipts to IsTaxIncluded true - not sure if this is of any help to you.